# Changing url path with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite

```
http://www.example.com/fr/index.html
```

to hide in the url folder `fr`

```
http://www.example.com/index.html
```

the htaccess file is in folder `fr`

this is my .htaccess file :

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.html(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ 

RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks !

Here my new .htaccess but... nothing

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /fr/
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $2.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.html(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution. I hope it can help someone :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Hide folder fr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+fr/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^fr/)^(.*)/$ /fr/$1 [L,NC]
# End

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.html(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/$1/ [R=301,L]
```